# Select values from two tables using Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have two tables as follows,

cabinet

```
cabinet_id     cabinet_name
1               Test1
2               Test2
3               Test3
```

cabinet_maping

```
id   product_id    cabinet_id   size
1      34              1            20
2      34              3            25
```

How can I select all cabinet_name from cabinet table where `cabinet_maping`.`product_id = 34` in Django

Expected Output as follows,

```
cabinet_id   cabinet_name    size
1             Test1            20
2             Test2            0
3             Test3            25
```

Comment: is a cabinet in a 1to1 relationship with cabinet_mapping? how are your models configured? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Django is not about manually querying tables (you can do that when djangos orm commands do not lead to the desired results or do not provide the query commands you need). It provides on ORM for that which goes hand-in-hand with models.

Answer (score 0):

I think that yours models could look like

```
class Cabinet(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

class cabinet_maping(models.Model):
     product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
     cabinet = models.ForeignKey(Cabinet)
     size = .....
```

You should do sth like this:

```
cabinet_name = cabinet_maping.objects.filter(product__id = 34)

for item in cabinet_name:
     print item.cabinet.id 
     print item.cabinet.name
     print item.size
```

I didn't check it but i think that should work (that works :))

Comment: I think this will return only cabinet_id with 1 and 3 which presented in cabinet_maping. It won't return cabinet_id 2

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Silwestpl that your models are wrong as using Foreign Key would make this query a lot easier. But just an answer to your question would be. I am assuming that you dont have any relationships between the two tables as you haven't mentioned any.

```
x = Cabinet_mapping.objects.filter(product_id = somevalue).distinct('cabinet_id')

response_list = []

for y in x:
    response_dict = {}
    response_dict['cabinet_id'] = y.cabinet_id
    response_dict['cabinet_name'] = cabinet.objects.get(id = y.cabinet_id).cabinet_name
    response_dict['size'] = y.size

    response_list.append(response_dict)

return response_list
```

This would be the answer according to the details you have provided.

But Ideally I would do something like this

```
class Product(models.Model):
   # id is generated automatically.
   ## any other fields that you want for product.

class Cabinet(models.Model):
   # again id is auto-genearated.
   cabinet_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   cabinet_size = models.IntegerField()
   products = models.ManytoManyField(Product)#This automatically maps product_id n cabinet_id.
```

And your query would be.

```
x = Cabinet.objects.filter(product.id=some_value)
print (x.id , x.cabinet_name, x.cabinet_size) # I used print, but you can use it anyway you want.
```

This would be what you require. Please use the second solution if you are looking into something serious.